# Using Selenium to retrieve all ID tags

Tags: c#, selenium

In my html source code I need to retrieve all values of the `Id` tag that starts with the word '*action*'.

So all `Id` tags that starts with the word '*action*' ('*action1*', '*action2*', '*action3*' etc) should be retrieved.

My code so far:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://hello/helloworld.aspx");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("action"));
var id2 = element.GetAttribute("action");
driver.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id,'action')]"))
```

would be all tags with id that starts with action for an xpath.

Comment: But then, How can I get the values of those Ids?

Comment: If you want the attribute id you'd just loop and use the getattribute for the value.

Comment: Its like <input type="hidden" name="action1" id="action1" value="1234"/> In that case I need to fetch the value of id action1 which is 1234

Comment: .getAttribute('value') use that on each element. You can also add [@value] to the selector to only get elements with the attribute value.